# How can count my result on my table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table for exam result, how can I filter and count my "correct" values on my table and somehow group them by User Number and Module? for example, i only want to count my "correct" values:

Comment: First, I would consider normalizing your table. DO you need multiple copies of the user id?

Comment: Why did you delete the table?

Answer (score 1):

First solution using `SUM` and `CASE`

```
SELECT `UserNo` ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `QuestionResult` = 'Correct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS QuestionResultCount ,
       `Module`
FROM `TableName`
GROUP BY `UserNo` ,
         `Module`
```

Second solution using `COUNT` and `WHERE` clause :
(Note: This could be better for large tables with proper indexes, since the DBE can use that index to filter the table while it can not be done with any `CASE..WHEN` based solutions.)

```
SELECT `UserNo` ,
        COUNT(`QuestionResult`) AS QuestionResultCount ,
       `Module`
FROM `TableName`
WHERE `QuestionResult` = 'Correct'
GROUP BY `UserNo` ,
         `Module`
```

Third solution using `COUNT` and `CASE` :

```
SELECT `UserNo` ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `QuestionResult` = 'Correct' THEN `QuestionResult` END) AS   QuestionResultCount ,
       `Module`
FROM `TableName`
GROUP BY `UserNo` ,
          `Module`
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b3a/5)

Comment: @samitha : Why are you doing this?)I like them before)

Comment: IF you want to get the count records with a specific filter, you do not need to use a `CASE..WHEN` statement. The DBE will not count that records which are not met your conditions. Also you should use it, if you want to get the cout for the `Correct` and the `Wrong` count in separate columns.

Comment: @Pred : There are different ways to do it

Comment: Yes you have, as always in IT.

Comment: My point here is if you have proper indexes and table stucture, the `CASE..WHEN` could use more resources (full table scan and filesort), while with the `WHERE` keyword, there is more chance to use an existing index (index seek or index scan). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14165/1

Comment: With another words: You can build an index to supply the `WHERE` conditions, but you can't do it with the `CASE..WHEN` statement

Comment: @Pred: I totally agree with you.But here I am just trying to show different ways to accomplish the same task – nothing more.

Comment: When I commented on your answer, there were only one solution (the `SUM(CASE..WHEN)` one, then you added another solutions via editing.

Comment: @Pred : I don't know what we are talking about – the first solution was written on the spot, then Raging Bull posted a fiddle, so I've tried two  more there and then I've posted them here.

Comment: My first comment is for the first solution, and when i wrote it, it was the only solution in this answer. Thats all. It does not matter pal, all thre solutions are good enough for small tables. I suggest that add a sentece to the answer for the `WHERE solution`. (Also this comment fight is irrelevant for the original question :))

Comment: @Pred : You find my solutions nice, I find you tip useful. I guess we are cool)

Comment: And once again the world is saved by the SO members :) Yes, we are cool ;) I did an edit to the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
UserNo, ModuleNo, COUNT(QuestionResult) as correctanswers
FROM yourtablename
WHERE
QuestionResult='Correct'
GROUP BY
UserNo, ModuleNo
```

You have to group twice if you want it grouped by the user and the module.

Comment: "WHERE" can be after "GROUP BY" ?

Comment: @samitha: `Where need to be after group by`??

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

1. Using `CASE`:

   ```
   SELECT UserNo,
          SUM(CASE WHEN QuestionResult = 'Correct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as QuestionResult, 
          ModuleNo as Module
   FROM TableName 
   GROUP BY `UserNo`,ModuleNo
   ORDER BY ModuleNo,UserNo
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   USERNO  QUESTIONRESULT   MODULE
   123456  3                1
   987456  2                1
   123456  4                2
   987456  1                2
   ```

   See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0070/9).
2. Using `WHERE` caluse:

   ```
   SELECT UserNo,
          COUNT(QuestionResult) as QuestionResult, 
          ModuleNo as Module
   FROM TableName 
   WHERE QuestionResult = 'Correct'
   GROUP BY `UserNo`,ModuleNo
   ORDER BY ModuleNo,UserNo
   ```

   See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0070/13).

Comment: Just so you know MySQL allows for a boolean expression inside a sum and will convert it to an integer for you: `SUM(QuestionResult = 'Correct')`

Answer (score -1):

Use [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

```
SELECT UserNo,
       COUNT(QuestionResult)
FROM TABLE
WHERE QuestionResult = 'Correct'
GROUP BY ModuleNo, ModuleNo
```

Comment: You have a typo, UerNo should be UserNo, you're also only going to return only one result per Module, not one result per user/Module.

Comment: Grouping by `ModuleNo` and `ModuleNo`? I hope that is a typo. ;-)